# Problems displaying dataTable in modal in html partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I asked a question here yesterday about this issue but got downvoted, probably because I didn't include any code which is understandable.

Hopefully this question will be more complete and allow you to help me more easily.

So I have 3 views in play:

**StudentsList**

*Script*

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "StudentsList";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutM.cshtml";
}
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/charts")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/formsaltcss")
@model Mvc.Models.StudentViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#AddStudentData').click(function () {
        var type = 'student';
        var id = 0;

        $('#holderArea').html('');
        if (!$('#studentDropDown option:selected').length) {
            ToastrWarning('Please select a student before running the report');
            return;
        }
        id = $('#studentDropDown').val();

        var data = { id: id };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Student/StudentAnalysisFiltered',
            async: false,   
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#holderArea').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*Relevant HTML*

```
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="margin-bottom0 text-center">Student Analysis</h3></div>


                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Student Name</label>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Students, new SelectList(Model.Students, "StudentID", "Name"), "Choose Student"
    , new { id = "studentDropDown", @class = "form-control input-sm", data_width = "100%" })
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                            <button id="AddStudentData" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Select</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="holderArea">
                            </div>
```

**StudentAnalysisSelected**
*Script*

```
@using Data
@using Mvc.Helpers
@model Mvc.Models.StudentViewModel
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/datatables")
<script>
    function StudentScoresModal(studentID, answer, result) {
        $('#scoresTable').hide();
        $('#scoresSpinner').show();
        $('#scoresModal').modal('show');

        var testID = @Html.Raw(Model.testID );

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/Student/StudentScoresDrillthrough",
            data: { 'studentID': studentID, 'answer': answer, 'result': result, 'testID': testID},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#scoresTable').html(data);
                $('#scoresTable').show();
                $('#scoresSpinner').hide();
            },
            error: function () {
                toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';
                toastr.options.backgroundpositionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';
                toastr.options.timeOut = 3000;
                toastr.error('Unable to get student results.');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

*Relevant HTML*

```
    <div id="holderArea">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="StudentScoresModal(id, '', '')" id="@q.StudentID">View Scores</button>
</div>

    <div class="modal in modal-stack" id="scoresModal" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Student Scores</strong></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive" id="scoresTable" style="display:none">
                            </div>
                            <div class="sk-cube-grid absolute-center top-85" id="scoresSpinner" style="display:none">
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
                                <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**StudentScoresPartial**

*Script*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#studentScores').dataTable({
            "data": @Html.Raw(Model.StudentScoresJson),
            "columns":[
                        { "sName": "StudentID" },
                        { "sName": "Answer" },
                        { "sName": "Result" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

*HTML*

```
<table id="studentScores" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>StudentID</th>
            <th>Answer</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Answer</th>
            <th>Response</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**How it all works**

On the 'StudentsList' view there is a dropdown with list of students, and a 'Select' button to filter on an individual. OnClick this clears the holderArea div and passes studentID to the controller method, which returns a partial view 'StudentAnalysisSelected' and places it inside the holderArea div.

Now a graph is loaded with details specific to the indivudual. When clicked the 'scoresTable' is hidden and the modal is shown and an ajax call is made to StudentScoresDrillthrough controller, which returns the 'StudentScores' partial that is placed into the html of 'scoresTable'.

**The problem**

Now this all works perfectly first time I filter by student. I click 'Select', the graph loads, I click the graph and the datatable displays neatly in the modal.

However for reasons unknown to me when I click 'Select' again to re-filter, and click on the graph that is loaded all I see is the modal appear with the loading spinner, and it stops there. No errors pertaining to datatables in the console, or anything out of the ordinary for that matter.

I appreciate this is a bit of a read, but i'd be keen to hear any thoughts on what could be causing my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming this is Asp.Net MVC.. You gotta add the relevant tags.

Comment: Done, thanks for that.

Comment: Getting anything in Console of Web Browser?

Comment: Nothing at all to suggest a problem @Shashank Sood

Answer (score 1):

It's because your dom is reloaded and so you loose your event attached.
If you attach ypur event like so, this should do, [see doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$('#AddStudentData').on('click',function () {});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip @Sylvain Guilbert but that hasn't done it unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

First try calling dataTable after filter button click using                  $('#studentScores').dataTable();
If this doesn't work 
Instead on your refilter click write:
    $('#studentScores').dataTable();
After your  partialview is fully loaded. And bind your list in table directly e.g :
    
    
    
    StudentID
    Answer
    Result
    
    
    
    @foreeach(var item in Model)
    {
        
            item.User
            item.Answer
            item.Response
        
    }

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. As it turned out, it was because I was calling the modal.Show before the table.Show... I moved it to after and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally tracked it down and it was because the modal show was called before the table show.

Thanks to those who posted suggestions, it's much appreciated